# Any research data on spelling mistakes in English?

Tags: orthography

I am developing a "did you mean?" suggestion for my project similar to Google's suggestion. To make the algorithm to work faster, I am looking for a data or any research done on English spelling mistakes.

I am looking for
1. When there is a spelling mistake, In most cases, how many characters are extra or less ?

Comment: I think this is the wrong site for your question. Try SE linguistics someone there might know of data related to the mechanics of the language. http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can definitely vouch that *definitely* is the most misspelt/misspelled word. I had one private student who drove me mad, no matter how often I corrected it, his next essay would have at least one *definately* chucked in there.  http://www.telegraph.co.uk/education/educationnews/5538890/Definitely-is-most-commonly-misspelt-word.html The article lists the top 20 misspelled (AmEng) /misspelt (BrEng) words.